# php find snippet of content from preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Ok say I have a paragraph of text:

> After getting cut for the first and
>   last time in his life, Durant watched
>   from the sofa as the American team
>   waltzed into the gold-medal game and
>   then was tested by Spain, ultimately
>   emerging with a 118-107 victory that
>   ended an eight-year gold-medal drought
>   for the senior U.S. men's national
>   team. But the gold-medal drought for
>   the Americans in the FIBA World
>   Championship remains intact, now at 16
>   years and counting as Team USA
>   prepares to head to Turkey without any
>   of the members of the so-called Redeem
>   Team from Beijing.

What I would like to do is to run a php **preg_match_all** a few keywords (say example 
'team' and 'for') on the text, and then retrieve a snippet (maybe 10 words before and 10 words after) for each of the result found.

Anyone has any idea how that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

- Get a list of all words and their offsets using `preg_match_all` with *PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE* flag.
- Iterate the words and find the search term.
- Get the *x* words before and after the match.

Here’s an example:

```
preg_match_all('/[\w-]+/u', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$term = 'team';
$span = 3;
for ($i=0, $n=count($matches[0]); $i<$n; ++$i) {
    $match = $matches[0][$i];
    if (strcasecmp($term, $match[0]) === 0) {
        $start = $matches[0][max(0, $i-$span)][1];
        $end = $matches[0][min($n-1, $i+$span+1)][1];
        echo ' … '.substr($str, $start, $end-$start).' … ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.squarebrackets.php

So this is one word with a separator:

```
([:word:].*[:punct:])
```

These are ten words with sep.

```
([:word:].*[:punct:]){10}
```

Something like this would be close to your solution:

```
([:word:].*[:punct:].){10}team([:punct:].[:word:].*){10}
```

Comment: 600 characters are not enough to describe all the problems with this answer.  Please, just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You might find a lot of interesting ideas in the Drupal search exerpt builder.

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/search_excerpt/6

This one is UTF8-safe and has all kinds of edge-cases covered.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this will do the trick having in mind that the words you search should be at about 4 words atleast distance or it will not match it.. you can change this and adjust. This way you can adjust the importance of the relation between the keywords

```
preg_match_all("~([\w]+[\s\- ,]+){0,3}watched([\s\- ,]+[\w]+){0,4}\ssofa([\s\- ,]+[\w]+){0,3}~i", $text, $matches);
```